# php fpdf, how to choose how many items to show up on a single page

Tags: php, jquery, fpdf

I am using a barcode labels jquery to generate barcodes to print but I have not been able to find anywhere online where a user can select the number of (images/etc..) so to create an fPDF to print. Is that even possible, to have a form with a select of number of images to show up in the pdf?

Comment: You have PHP code that generates the PDF, right? It should be possible for you to determine there how many items to select.

Comment: I do have he PHP code, the issue is that on the selecting, is how many barcodes to showup on the fpdf...if only 1 or 20...